# Why do I receive an invalid type (list) error when using glama()?

Tags: r, glm, moving-average

When using `glarma` package in R to run a moving average linear model, I receive the following error: 
`**Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ -1 + X + offset(offset.nb),  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'y'**`

```
set.seed(2908)
  library("glarma")
  d <- structure(list(Count = c(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21), 
    Intercept = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), explanatory = c(0.1, 
    0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99)), .Names = c("Count", 
"Intercept", "explanatory"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

  y <- d[, 1]
  X <- as.matrix(d[, 2:3])
  glarmamod <- glarma(y, X, thetaLags = 3, type = "NegBin", method = "NR",
                    residuals = "Pearson", alphaInit = 0,
                    maxit = 100, grad = 1e-6)
  glarmamod
```

Why do I receive this error?

Comment: Please do not provide your data through an image.  No one wants to type it all in.  Instead, please use `dput(d)` and paste the results into your question.

Comment: @G5W, Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I'm guessing `y` has to be a vector, not a dataframe. Try `y=d[[1]]`

Comment: @useR, no I tried, it doesn't work

Comment: Using `[[ ]]` for assigning y changes the error message, so it does actually answer the question asked. That said, the code still doesn't run, but instead throws a different error: `Error in GL$cov %*% GL$ll.d : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments` plus a host of `iteration limit reached` warnings. That error results from the `mySolve()` function (called in the midst of `glarmamod()`) not being able to invert the second derivative matrix of the log-likelihood to obtain the estimated covariance matrix of the parameters.

Comment: @crazybilly This could be due to the fact that sample size is only 10. Changing `type` to `"Poi"` and `method = "FS"` allows the model to be run. This suggests that `n=10` is not enough to estimate the extra parameter for negative binomial. By increasing the sample size to, say 1000 (by random sampling), both models with negative binomial and poisson distribution ran successfully.

Comment: @useR: I enhanced the sample size to 1000 but still getting the same error. I also tried with type= 'Poi' and method= 'FS' but again the same error'

Comment: @crazybilly: Yes right it changes the error, so what is the solution for the new error?

Comment: Thanks, everybody. your comments really helped and I was able to solve it. here is the solution: changing the number of samples has no effect . it works even with 10 samples. I changed type to "Poi" and method to "FS" and  y=d[[1]] and thetaLags = 7

Comment: Nice! Consider answering the question yourself with the full solution, then accepting your own answer.